# Android Facebook Logout Error

Tags: android, facebook

I give the user the option to logout in my android app. ***Sometimes*** the logout process is stopped by the following errors.

```
 08-18 00:44:25.253: W/System.err(510): com.facebook.android.FacebookError:auth.expireSession failed
 08-18 00:44:25.302: W/System.err(510):     at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$1.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:86)
 08-18 00:44:25.302: W/FacebookError(510): com.facebook.android.FacebookError: auth.expireSession failed
```

Here is my Logout code.

```
     private void logout() {

    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
          {
                 SessionStore.clear(home.this); // clear token and expire value
                 Editor editor = Prefs.edit();
                 editor.clear();
                 editor.commit();

                 cancelNotification();
          }

          @Override
          public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
              Log.d("IOExcenption", e.toString());
          }

          @Override
          public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
              Log.d("FileNotFoundException", e.toString());
          }

          @Override
          public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
              Log.d("MalformedUrlExpection", e.toString());
          }

          @Override
          public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Log.w("FacebookError", e.toString());
          }
        });
```

Anyone have this problem? Or see something wrong?